# protected route not rendering protected componet after authentication

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

So I have a react app and I want to redirect users to a dashboard after authentication. I am using react-router-dom. The surprising thing is that after all setup and I try to access the protected route without authentication it redirects me back to the home page which works well also, when I console log to check if user verification function works. it returns authenticated user which means that is also working well. But when I sign in  as a user react is supposed to render the dashboard but unfortunately it doesn't. I am so confused at the moment. Please some assistance would be highly appreciated. Thanks

ProtectedRoute.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Route,Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

const ProtectedRoute = ({isAuth:isLoggedin,component:Component,...rest})=>{
    console.log(Component,isLoggedin)
    return (
        <Route 
    {...rest} 
   
    render={(props)=>{
        if(isLoggedin){
            return <Component />
        }else{
           return(
            <Redirect  to={{
                pathname:'/',
                state: {from: props.location}
            }}
            />
           )
        }
    }
    }
    />
    )
}
export default ProtectedRoute;

ProtectedRoute.propTypes={
    isAuth: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
}
```

App.js

```
const App = ()=>{
    const [isClicked, setIsClicked]= useState(false);
    const [username,setUsername] = useState()
    const [pass,setPass] = useState();
    const [isLoggedIn,setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
    const [authUser,setAuthUser] = useState({})

    


    const disableScroll =()=>{
        document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        document.querySelector('html').scrollTop = window.scrollY;
        }
        
        const enableScroll=()=>{
        document.body.style.overflow = null;
        }
    const handleLogin = () =>{
        setIsClicked(!isClicked);
        if(!isClicked){disableScroll()}
        else if(isClicked){enableScroll()}
    }
    const handleLogout = ()=>{
        setIsLoggedIn(!isLoggedIn)
        {<Redirect to={{
            pathname: "/",
            state: { from: props.location }
             }}
             />}
      console.log(isLoggedIn)
    }
    const getUser = ()=>{
            Users.forEach((user)=>{
                if(user.username === username)return user
            })
    }
    
    const login=()=>{
        const curUser = Users.filter((el)=>{
            if(el.username === username) return el
        })
          if(curUser[0].username === username && curUser[0].pass.toString() === pass){
            setAuthUser(curUser[0]);
            setIsLoggedIn(!isLoggedIn)
            enableScroll();
          }else{alert('invalid username or password')}
      }
    
    return( 
        <LoginContext.Provider value={{isClicked,setIsClicked,handleLogin,setUsername,
        setPass,login,isLoggedIn,authUser,setAuthUser,handleLogout}}>
        <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}>
            <HomePage/>
        </Route> 
        <ProtectedRoute  exact path='/Dashboard' isAuth={isLoggedIn}   component={Dashboard}/>
        </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
        
        </LoginContext.Provider>
        
       
        
        
        
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Seems you create the "auth context" but don't use it in the nested children components? After authenticating where do you attempt to redirect to dashboard route? Seems that logic is in your `HomePage` component? You also are using both the `component` prop and children in the "/" path, pick one or the other.

Comment: @Drew Thanks for your suggestions. The flow of the app should be user logs in and app redirects to dashboard. I have divided the dashboard into different components then imported them to dashboard.js. Also globally I am using the context api to access some functions and variable across the app.

Comment: The issue I am having now is that once a user is authenticated I expect react to render the dashboard but that is not happening, it just sits there but when I try to access the dashboard by passing in the  /Dashborad url it redirects back to the homepage which is exactly what I wanted. In all the app does not execute the first 'if' block but the else block works well in the ProtectRender component. I hope I am making some sense. Thanks